# Nothing happens when I type a "runas" password at the command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I am executing an exe from a command prompt. The exe works only in a WOW64 command prompt. And I am signing in as a different user with the command below:

```
runas /user:username "D:\xxx.exe"
```

After this, I am prompted for a password. But nothing is happening when I type or paste the password. The cursor is not moving. Why is this?

Comment: That's normal..

Comment: Did you hit enter after typing/pasting the password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per what it says in the comments, the behavior that you are seeing is for your own protection. To prevent other people from being able to see the password that you are typing, it shows nothing.

When you hit enter, the password is submitted.